# Creating mysql users via linux command line?

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm working on a python script to setup servers quickly and it basically has a list of commands I want to execute on the linux commandline.

I can install all the software I need but not sure how to create a mysql user solely via command line?  I can I can go into the mysql shell and do it but is there a way to do it solely from the linux shell(once the user is created I can do all the database setup remotely with a python script)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You do it with the same query you'd use in the client, but execute it on the command line with the `-e` flag:

```
mysql -uroot -prootpw -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO username@hostname IDENTIFIED BY 'userpassword'"
```

Or pipe in the command

```
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO username@hostname IDENTIFIED BY 'userpassword'" | mysql -uroot -prootpw
```

Comment: But it requires a running MySQL doesn't it?

Comment: @Qwe Any modification to a MySQL database including simply setting the root password requires a running MySQL instance.